# How can I most efficiently load images from a PostGreSQL database using SpringBoot and React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring

I save an image, which is loaded into a Spring backend with React, in a PostGreSQL database as type bytea. Well, if I read out the image, or several at a time, I get an array of many bytes. Is that the most efficient solution to load images from PostGreSQL and display them in React? Because with several pictures it can happen that you have to wait 4s (about 15 pictures).

**I don't get an error, it's all about performance**

[image]

My JavaCode:

```
...
 while (rs.next()) {



                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                        for (int i = 1; i < intRS + 1; i++) {


                               String column_name = meta.getColumnName(i);


                               switch (meta.getColumnType(i)) {

                               case 2003:

                                     obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case -5:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getInt(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getInt(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 16:

                                     obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 2004:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getBlob(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getBlob(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 8:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getDouble(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getDouble(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 6:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getFloat(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getFloat(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 4:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getInt(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getInt(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case -9:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getNString(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getNString(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 12:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getString(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getString(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case -6:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getInt(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getInt(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 5:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getInt(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getInt(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 91:

                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getDate(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getDate(column_name));

                                     break;

                               case 93:

                                     obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL

                                                  : rs.getTimestamp(column_name));

                                     break;

                               default:



                                     obj.put(column_name,

                                                 rs.getObject(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getObject(column_name));

                                     break;

                               }



                        }

  ArrayJS.put(obj);
}
```

And i my React code i map over the JSONArray comming from my Backend an format the Image Array like this:

```
var img = atob(arrayBufferToBase64(data.Projektbild));
```

Comment: You're sending binary data as JSON. Binary data should be sent as binary, otherwise your byte value of `100` takes 3 bytes instead of 1. Not to mention the unnecessary serialization and deserialization of JSON data.

Answer (score -1):

For large binary data, it's generally much faster to store the data in the filesystem (or an object store like S3) and store a link in the database.

Comment: @ dssjoblom This is not possible because the application runs in a cloud

Comment: But you haven't any disk space on your cloud?

Comment: I use Pivotal as a PaaS Service

Comment: @schorle88 I haven't used Pivotal, but see e.g. here: https://docs.pivotal.io/application-service/2-10/operating/pas-file-storage.html

Comment: @dssjoblom Ok, I'll take a look, thanks. But is that the best solution? I mean I also want to update, delete, etc. pictures.

Comment: @schorle88 All of those operations also work on filesystems or cloud storage. I do think it is the best, and the "normal" solution.

Comment: @dssjoblom it's because you're giving bad advice unrelated to the problem. There's nothing wrong with storing an image in a `bytea`. There's everything wrong with sending that `bytea` as JSON.

Comment: @Kayaman that's /also/ wrong, but I'm 100% certain that an RDBMS will not perform at the level of a filesystem or object store when it comes to serving large files.

Comment: @dssjoblom that is an issue that exists, however it's not an issue which has an impact here. If it becomes apparent that Postgres' TOASTed `bytea` column is not good enough (which would be surprising tbh), then alternative storage can be considered. The performance hotspot here is the JSON, so this question deserves a downvote for not being helpful (and even being confusing for taking attention away from the real problem).

Comment: @Kayaman Let's disagree to disagree. I actually wrote an application like this a long time ago (in MySQL though), storing the images in the DB, and I don't recommend it.